# Assign a value to an awk variable

Tags: awk

Why does awk not able to print the variable from a condition?

```
cat CRND0103-2013-WY_Sundance_8_NNW.txt | awk '{ ($7 == '-9999.0') ? a = 'true' : a = 'false'; print $7, a }'
```

or even `awk '{b = 'true'; print b}'` does not work. Can anyone tell why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `'` to `"` in your statement.

```
awk '{b = "true"; print b;}' 
          ^    ^
```